# Ruby scoped method value techniques

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class Curious
  def calculation
    def calculation
      @retrieved_value
    end
    @retrieved_value = #some kind of intensive process
  end
end
```

Doing the above, the outer method will be run the first time and the inner method will provide the value subsequent times. What's the advantage or disadvantage of doing that over a single non-nested method that just does `@retrieved_value ||= #some kind of intensive process`?

Comment: "Nested method" is probably a bad term, as the method is available outside the scope of the "enclosing" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're redefining the `calculation` method for the `Curious` class. This will affect other instances:

```
a = Curious.new
a.calculation # calls "outer" method, this sets @retrieved_value
a.calculation # calls "inner" method

b = Curious.new
b.calculation # calls "inner" method, @retrieved_value not set
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO there's little advantage, with a disadvantage of being somewhat opaque at first glance.

It's possible there could be some scoping advantages depending on the nature of the intensive process.